# Bash variable READLINE_LINE always empty

Tags: bash, xorg, readline

I was looking for a way to share clipboard between bash and X, but the variable $READLINE_LINE and $READLINE_POINT is always empty. Does anyone know the reason? Bash version is 4.3.30. See the post for a solution for clipboard sharing. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994563/integrate-readlines-kill-ring-and-the-x11-clipboard

Comment: [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-READLINE_005fLINE) says those variables are for use with `bind -x` -- in what context are you using those vars?

Comment: I have defined a function _xyank in my bashrc and bind it to ctrl y to replace the default behavior with
bind -m emacs -x '"\ey": _xyank'

Comment: See also [Modify $READLINE_LINE and $READLINE_POINT values inside bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25178632/2173773)

Comment: The functions and binding are all souced in the .bashrc file. I guess they are run in the same process.